# Escaping HTML using htmlentities in textarea but turn back to HTML for database

Tags: php, textarea, xss, html-entities

So I have slight problem. The PHP program I am working on allows web designers to post some code sometimes, and is put into a backend database. Sometimes the designers may also want to discuss html entities.

So let's say the designer adds a line of code to database like this:

```
<p>hellos friend</p>
```

So I use PDO to stick this line in the database without escaping it, and everything is fine, it shows up good. Now, I want the web designer to be able to edit this, so when I pull it out of database I use this code after:

```
$post = htmlentities($post);
```

It is good now that I can insert this into my editor:

```
<textarea>$post</textarea>
```

But we have problem because when this guy edit this code, he submit and it go back into the database and now it got HTML entities and has **& lt ;** instead of < and **& gt ;** instead of >  (it is hard to type this on SA it re-encodes it)

```
&lt;p&gt;hellos friend&lt;/p&gt;
```

So now it's wrong in database, so when I display it again, it show the entities.

So maybe I can run the opposite of **htmlentities** after editing it and re-add all the entities, if there is such a thing, but that brings another problem:

What if a web designer is telling other guy "Hey man, this is what an html entity is, it is typed like this: **&** **lt;** you should use it"

Then THAT is going to turn out to get stuck back into NOT being an entity, you see what I mean? Is there a solute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `html_entity_decode()` function. It is the reverse of `htmlentities()`. It converts the &lt back into <

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

For your second issue you would need to have the designers escape the html entities somehow. I don't think PHP has a way to escape them but I could be wrong. It might be something you would have to implement yourself, like have the designer put a `\` in front of the entity to set it apart from the entities that are suppose to be converted to HTML and then parse the input looking for escaped entities.